# Daisy chaining 2 monitors ( Dell P2214H ) with macbook pro (13 inch , mid 2012 )

Tags: mac

How can I connect 2 monitors [Dell P2214H](http://www.dell.com/ed/business/p/dell-p2214h/pd) with macbook pro (2012) that has only one thunderbolt output ?

Comment: Need better detail on which model, there are 6 different 2012 13" MacBook Pro models. See http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/index-macbookpro.html

Comment: @Tetsujin It is the [core I5](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.5-13-mid-2012-unibody-usb3-specs.html) one , but with 8 GB ram .

Comment: does this monitor supports daisy-chain technology ??

Comment: You would have to buy a [splitter](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?O=&sku=1234854&gclid=CjwKEAjwz4u9BRCbioK3stnBznESJADA75xbxRLMhqJ738AE4LX9chel-IarjtIfGTuuSdb3pFSgQxoCpC3w_wcB&is=REG&ap=y&m=Y&c3api=1876%2C92051677682%2C&A=details&Q=).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you cam do this. The Dell monitor above has a display port but does not explicitly say thunderbolt. Usualy, a monitor with thunderbolt has 2 connections: from the computer to the monitor, then from the monitor to another monitor.  In this case, you can try using a USB to VGA/DVI/HDMI/DP adaptor to get the second monitor running, with first monitor connected via Thunderbolt (mini display port connection fits).